# ADO.NET SQL Transaction - Only 1 call to database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I am reviewing some code which is inserting some data into a MSSQL Database (MSSQL2014) using a Stored Procedure.

Each row of data results in a call to that database.

This is obviously inefficient for a number of reasons; not least of which is the fact that a call has to be made over the network for each line of data.

I am surmising that if they simply wrap all these individual sqlcommand calls (ExecuteNonQuery) into a transaction then this will ultimately result in a "batch insert" of sorts. When you actually "COMMIT" the transaction, the call accross the connection is made.

Is this correct? Will this send all the sqlcommands to the server in a single call? I have not been able to find a diagram or documentation which outlines the communication between the client and server when a transaction is used.

```
--> Begin Transaction

-> ExecuteNonQuery
-> ExecuteNonQuery
-> ExecuteNonQuery
-> ExecuteNonQuery
-> ExecuteNonQuery
-> ExecuteNonQuery
-> ExecuteNonQuery
-> ...

--> Commit Transaction (my assumption is that each of the SqlCommands 
    are sent over the connection object at this point)
```

On a sidenote I am more inclined to recommend that the developer rewrites the routine to make use of SQLBulkCopy or TableValued Parameters. This would however necessitate the re-factoring of the database stored procedure.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It can be because for each row of data you are inserting, if one row fails, it can be _Rollbacked_. So that those that is inserted will still remain in the database.

Comment: There will be no batch insert.  All the transaction will do is give you the ability to commit the inserts so others would be able to see the changes. No performance gains and if anything a performance hit. Not knowing what you are wanting to do here it would be hard to give you a proper answer.

Comment: @CraigSelbert - seems you have just answered my question. I am trying to lessen the impact of network latency between the client and server by minimising round trip calls to the database server but if i am to interpret your answer correctly, a transaction will not help achieve this.

Comment: Use table-valued parameters See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.120).aspx and here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @CraigSelbert if you want to record this as an answer pls do so and i will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There will be no batch insert. Neither the client nor the server optimize across statements. ADO.NET has no machinery to understand the SQL that you are sending. It cannot optimize anything. The server could but does not.

There will be a performance gain by using a transaction like this because the inserts do not need to flush the log as long as the transaction is pending.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no batch insert. All the transaction will do is give you the ability to commit the inserts so others would be able to see the changes. No performance gains and if anything a performance hit. Not knowing what you are wanting to do here it would be hard to give you a proper answer